# when is user authenticated when using asp.net CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, createuserwizard

I am using the asp.net CreateUserWizard and I have LoginCreatedUser=true. I also have the "OnCreatedUser" property for the CreateUserWizard control to a method and thought the auth ticket would be created at that point but it is not.

**When exactly is the authentication ticket (Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"]) populated?**

I need to know so that during registration I can modify the UserData and add it to the auth ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before doing the following:

1. In the CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser event you know for a fact the user is created, so save the username to HttpContext.Items array.
2. Check for the username in HttpContext.Items in the page's PreRender() event (it'll run after the CreatedUser() step). If it's there overwrite your authentication ticket

To test this make sure you later decrypt the authentication ticket and check the UserData. In my own projects this is how I handle having a user logged in at registration and have some of their info injected into the auth ticket's UserData.